# Can't implement lod_options in Metal shader

Tags: ios, shader, metal

Trying to use bias in my kernel code:

```
return sample(source, uv, bias(lod)).xyz;
```

And have this error:

```
ERROR: unkown type or function name: 'bias'
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `bias` is in the `metal` namespace. Do you have a `using namespace metal;` directive at the top of your source file? If not, you may need to qualify the name as `metal::bias`. In any case, you also need to ensure you're including Metal's standard library via `#include <metal_stdlib>`

Comment: Thanks! As I understand I'm on wrong direction. I use CIKernel to implement shaders, and it doesn't have full functionality and all the options from MSL, so I don't have lod options. Will dig it more...

Comment: In the future, it would save some time if you tag such questions with `core-image`, since as you say, there are some significant differences between CIKL kernels and MSL shaders.